# call click event on added div

Tags: jquery, click

I am using jQuery to build a simple app to save your notations. I add items to a list using a form and this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.add').click(function() {
    var item = $('#todo')
    if( $('#todo').val().length> 0)  {
        $('div.lists').prepend("<div class='listItem'>"+item.val()+"</div>");
        localStorage["myKey"] = JSON.stringify($(".lists").html());
        $('#itemForm').toggle();
        $('#todo').val(' ')
    }
});
});
```

This part works fine. But when I try to add an id to a specific clicked div, nothing happens. I do this with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div.listItem').on("click",function() {
    $(evt.target).attr('id', '#selected');
});
});
```

And I can't find the mistake. I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please put your code on jsfiddle

Comment: You are probably better off using a class rather than an id. Some browsers can have issues if you try to add more than one id with the same name, or if you remove an id and try to apply it to another dom element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because you add your elements ***dynamically***:

```
$('div.lists').prepend("<div class='listItem'>"+item.val()+"</div>");
```

These dynamically added elements don't have event handlers attached because they are added later after the document is ready and your `$('div.listItem').on("click",function() {` is run.

Try delegated event instead

```
$(document).on("click",'div.listItem',function() {
    $(evt.target).attr('id', '#selected');
});
```

Side note: I recommend using a class `selected` instead of an Id to avoid problems that may occur if there is more than 1 element with the same Id.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.listItem').on("click",function() {
    $(this).attr('id', '#selected');
});
```

But this makes no sense tbh - this will add an id of #selected

Is that what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use a class rather than an id to determine which element was selected you could do something like this:

```
$('div.listItem').on("click",function() {
  // Remove any other items with .selected
  $('div.listItem.selected').removeClass('selected');

  // Add class to the clicked element
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks khanh, you got me on the right track. What you posted didn't work initially. I then wrote this

```
$(document).on("click",'.listItem',function() {
if ( $( this ).hasClass( "selected" ) ) {
$(this).removeClass('selected');
var select=0;
}
else {
$(this).addClass('selected');
var select=1;
}
```

and this does the job. The variables are for other purposes :)